# Codeigniter 3: Insert array form to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm new with Codeigniter and I'm having some trouble inserting arrays into my database. An error kept popping out that I can't insert array to my database.

**Here's my HTML form:**

```
<?= form_open('profile/profile_submit'); ?>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="headCheckHide"></th>
        <th><center>Name</center></th>
        <th><center>Date of Birth</center></th>
        <th><center>Occupation</center></th>
        <th><center>Educ. attainment</center></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sibTable">
    <tr class="product-item">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="siblingName[]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="siblingBirthDate[]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="siblingOccupation[]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control form-input" name="siblingEducAttainment[]" >
                <option value="" selected>-Please select-</option>
                <option value="less than high school">less than high school</option>
                <option value="Some college but no degree">Some college but no degree</option>
                <option value="Associates Degree">Associates Degree</option>
                <option value="Elementary Graduate">Elementary Graduate</option>
                <option value="Secondary Graduate">Secondary Graduate</option>
                <option value="College Graduate">College Graduate</option>
                <option value="Master's Degree">Master's Degree</option>
                <option value="Professional Degree">Professional Degree</option>
                <option value="Doctorate Degree">Doctorate Degree</option>
                </select>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?= form_submit('submit','Save', 'class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect"');?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**My Controller for the form**

```
 public function profile_submit(){
    $siblings=array(

        'name' => $this->input->post('siblingName'),
        'birthDate' => $this->input->post('siblingBirthDate'),
        'occupation' => $this->input->post('siblingOccupation'),
        'educAttainment' => $this->input->post('siblingEducAttainment')
    );

    $this->profile_model->submit_profile($siblings);
    redirect('profile','refresh'); //name of the html file
}
```

**My model for (profile_model.php)**

```
 function submit_profile($siblings){
        $this->db->insert('tbl_st_profile_sibling',$siblings);
}
```

this is my model with the error: **can't insert array into database.**
Can anyone please help? thank you.

Comment: It will be better if you give us the error message as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store array data into DB you need to use loops to insert one.

```
function submit_profile($siblings){
   foreach($siblings['name'] as $key => $siblingName) {
      $dataToSave = array(
         'name' => $siblingName,
        'birthDate' => $siblings['siblingBirthDate'][$key],
        'occupation' => $siblings['siblingOccupation'][$key],
        'educAttainment' => $siblings['siblingEducAttainment'][$key]
      );
      $this->db->insert('tbl_st_profile_sibling', $dataToSave);
   }
}
```

UPDATE : Even you can use insert_batch to skip insertion in loop

```
function submit_profile($siblings){
   foreach($siblings['name'] as $key => $siblingName) {
      $dataToSave[] = array(
        'name' => $siblingName,
        'birthDate' => $siblings['siblingBirthDate'][$key],
        'occupation' => $siblings['siblingOccupation'][$key],
        'educAttainment' => $siblings['siblingEducAttainment'][$key]
      );
   }
      $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_st_profile_sibling', $dataToSave); 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to insert multiple input data at a time with the same name, don't worry please follow my instructions as given below

Changes in Controller:

```
public function profile_submit(){
    $submit_status = $this->profile_model->submit_profile();
    if( $submit_status == "TRUE"){
     redirect('profile','refresh'); //name of the html file
    }else{
     // Do Something else..
    }

}
```

Changes in Model:

```
function submit_profile(){

      $siblingsCount = count($this->input->post('siblingName')); 
      if($siblingsCount != null){
         $itemValues=0;
         $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_st_profile_sibling(name,birthDate,occupation,educAttainment) VALUES ";
         $queryValue = "";
         for($i=0;$i<$siblingsCount;$i++) {
             $name = $this->input->post('name');
             $birthDate = $this->input->post('birthDate');
             $occupation = $this->input->post('occupation');
             $educAttainment = $this->input->post('educAttainment');
             if(!empty($name[$i])) {
                 $itemValues++;
                 if($queryValue!="") {
                     $queryValue .= ",";
                 }

                 $queryValue .= "('" . $name[$i] . "', '" . $birthDate[$i] . "', '" . $occupation[$i] . "', '" . $educAttainment[$i] . "')";
             }
         }
       $sql = $query.$queryValue;
       if($itemValues!=0) {
        if (!$this->db->query($sql)) {
         echo "FALSE";
        }else {
         echo "TRUE";
        }
       }
      }
}
```

I hope this may help you...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the array you are saving into database the actual issue is with the post fields thy are in array format siblingName[]. So you need to convert then into strings so that this can be saved easily.

convert the array into coma separated list and then save in database.

```
    $siblingName = implode(",",$_POST['siblingName']);
    $siblingBirthDate= implode(",",$_POST['siblingBirthDate']);
    $siblingOccupation= implode(",",$_POST['siblingOccupation']);
    $siblingEducAttainment= implode(",",$_POST['siblingEducAttainment']);


   $siblings=array(

      'name' => $siblingName,
      'birthDate' => $siblingBirthDate,
      'occupation' => $siblingOccupation,
      'educAttainment' => $siblingEducAttainment
   );
```

Comment: I'm inserting the data per separate rows. However, thanks for the help :). This might help me in some of my code through the development

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo count($var); ?>" />


for($i=0;$i < count($var);$i++)
{

    <tr class="product-item">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="siblingName<?php echo $i; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="siblingBirthDate<?php echo $i; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="siblingOccupation<?php echo $i; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control form-input" name="siblingEducAttainment<?php echo $i; ?>" >
            <option value="" selected>-Please select-</option>
            <option value="less than high school">less than high school</option>
            <option value="Some college but no degree">Some college but no degree</option>
            <option value="Associates Degree">Associates Degree</option>
            <option value="Elementary Graduate">Elementary Graduate</option>
            <option value="Secondary Graduate">Secondary Graduate</option>
            <option value="College Graduate">College Graduate</option>
            <option value="Master's Degree">Master's Degree</option>
            <option value="Professional Degree">Professional Degree</option>
            <option value="Doctorate Degree">Doctorate Degree</option>
            </select>
        </td>   
    </tr>

}


$count = $this->input->post('count');
for($i=0;$i < $count;$i++)
{
    $siblings=array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('siblingName'.$i),
        'birthDate' => $this->input->post('siblingBirthDate'.$i),
        'occupation' => $this->input->post('siblingOccupation'.$i),
        'educAttainment' => $this->input->post('siblingEducAttainment'.$i)
    );

    $this->profile_model->submit_profile($siblings);
}
```